# How to match against the longest possible string with regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need to match strings of numbers against the longest possible match.

For example:

Full number:
2389466849

I need to match against:

23894

or

2389

If I want to make sure that I get the longest possible match ONLY, how can I accomplish this?  Is this best done with regular expression or in some other way?

Please give examples.

Comment: As I understand, in the given text: "123456789", if you search for "23467" you wanna return "234", right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for grabbing full number by using a partial match then use:

```
# all possible partial matching/non-matching strings
arr=( 23894 2389 2388 238946 )

# convert them into regex
s=$(printf "%s|" ${arr[@]} | sed 's/|$//')

# find longest matching pattern in input
egrep -o "$s" <<< "2389466849"
238946
```

Comment: I need to do the opposite.  I need to find the longest match of the short version based on the full number.

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: Full number: 2389466849 - I need to find the longest partial string that matches this number given more than one potential match, for example 23894 and 2389 and 238.  I need to be able to decide 23894 is the longest possible match given the options.

Comment: So your input is a set of strings A and a string b. As output you want the longest string in A, which is a sub string of b, right?

Comment: Opposite, string b is a sub of string a

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression cannot describe your type of problem. There might be some regular expression tools with additional features that can solve your problem, but if you wanna use a tool that can literally only find strings described by a regular expression, that is not possible. Your problem requires computation.

Answer (score 0):

With posix basic regular expressions (i.e. with `grep`), use `23894?` or `23894\|2389`. With posix extended regular expressions (`grep -E`): `23894|2389`

Posix regular expressions (unlike some other varieties) always match the longest match out of the set of possibilities which start at the earliest possible starting point.

The earliest starting point rule means that if your target were:

```
23890000023894
```

the match `23894?` would match the earlier `2389`, so it's not strictly longest-match. If you need the longest match anywhere in the string, that's a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm thinking.

```
regexes=( 23894 2389 )
test=2389466849
tmp=( )
for reg in ${regexes[@]}; do if [[ $test =~ $reg ]]; then
 tmp=( ${tmp[@]} $reg ); fi; done
maxlen=0
for match in ${tmp[@]}; do if [[ ${#match} > $maxlen ]]; then
 maxlen=${#match}; fi; done
```

Then based on that, you would know the longest substring that matched. If you wanted, you could also print it out with a similar loop to the last one, but with `[[ ${#match} = $maxlen ]]` and `echo`.

I really feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing this, but you are just working with Bash.